# Windows 10 - Keyboard Shortcut to Get to Task Bar Items

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows 7, I could press the Windows key then hit escape and then tab and I would get focus on my task bar items.  From there, I could use the right and left arrow keys to go through the list of items I have on my task bar.

How do I do this in Windows 10?   I am not looking to open a specific program right off the bat (which I can do using Windows key + 1, 2, 3, etc...).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> focuses the first item in the task bar. Then you can use arrows for navigation or press the shortcut again to select following item.

- [List of Windows shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a direct shortcut for this, but you can use a workaround like you were doing for Windows 7. There are 2 that I can think of:

1. You can use the "Windows key + B" to set the focus to the notification area (bottom right of the screen) and then hit "shift + tab" and the focus should go to your taskbar. You can then use the arrows (left and right) to go through the applications that are open.
2. You can hit the Windows button twice, then hit "tab" twice and you should be in the taskbar. You can now use the arrows (left and right) to go through the applications that are open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to set a keyboard shortcut like so:

```
#Space::WinActivate, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
```

Now, `Windows key + Space` will focus the taskbar.